# Static external IP for outgoing calls from Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Cloud Function that has to call an external API. This API does IP address based whitelisting. Is there a way to have a static external IP for all calls from a Cloud Function, without having to maintain a VM with a custom reverse proxy? Cloud NAT maybe?

Thanks,
  inki

Comment: See also  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112629904  via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811882/possible-to-get-static-ip-address-for-google-cloud-functions

Answer (score 2):

It's been one year, but for those with the same question, you need to:

1. Create a **NAT Gateway**
2. Create a **Serverless VPC Access** and configure to send all traffic through the VPC
3. **Connect your Cloud Function** to the Serverless VPC Access

So you can have your Cloud Function's traffic outgoing through the VPC -> NAT Gateway with a static external IP

Comment: I've tried to set this up, then deploy a function that hits ipify.org to prove the egress settings are right, but most http requests hang. I can reach Google domains, but not others. I suspect it's got something to do with internal ips skipping the NAT, but I'm stuck on how to debug. I switched on NAT logging but see no activity. Any tips?

Comment: @Chris, go to GCP Console -> Cloud Functions -> Edit. Double-check at Networking if choose "Route all traffic through the VPC connector" on the "Egress settings" section

Comment: Thanks @surfingonthenet! It turned out that my NAT mapping was wrong. I needed "All primary and secondary IP ranges for all subnets" so it found the VPC access connector's IPs.

Answer (score 1):

In the short-term, you can set up Cloud NAT to send traffic from a single IP.

Long-term, Google is working to add this feature, and is already testing it with a subset of users. If you'd like to participate: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScUcy5xeDZa015fPlWzNdpW3eYQdBAkBeotvXPdD6ByYSj8MA/viewform